# shopping in vs shopping on

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know if there is a difference in the following sentence depending on the preposition. Both seem to be correct.
I saw a celebrity while I was shopping in/on Oxford St.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you shop "in" a specific store, market, mall, village square, etc. You shop "on" a street. "I was shopping in Oxford St." wouldn't actually be correct, although the audience would understand what was meant. "I was shopping in a store on Oxford St." would be accurate.

Comment: To add onto this, though not completely related, when it comes to online stores, you shop "on" them.  "I was shopping on Amazon," "I was shopping on Etsy", etc.